# Javascript: How to set in a callback an optional parameter with the content of a variable

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, default

I have to provide a callback as a parameter to a function.

The callback will be called by the function with certain parameters. But I need to add some extra variable data on each call.
So let's say the callback is: `function(par1, par2, my_par=my_variable) { ...`
par1 and par2 are the parameters that the function will pass when invoking the callback. And my_par is the optional parameter I need to have differnent values on each call so it can be accessed from inside the callback.

It doesn't work. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the third parameter each time then?

Comment: Can you clarify how the value of the optional parameter `my_par` should be determined? You say it's supposed to be optional but also that the function will only be called with the first two parameters. Furthermore, that `my_par` needs a different value every time. This sounds more like you need partial application perhaps, rather than an optional parameter but it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to make out your actual problem since you didn't provide a working example of your problem, but this may help:

```js
function executeTheCallback(cb) {
  cb();
}

function theCallback(greeting, name = 'Anonymous') {
  console.log(`${greeting} ${name}!`);
}

executeTheCallback(theCallback.bind(null, 'Hello')); // Hello Anonymous!
executeTheCallback(theCallback.bind(null, 'Hello', 'World')); // Hello World!
```